# Using ContextMenu in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

There is an application I want to make using C#. This is part of it's UI:

[image: Application with a menu at the top and a tree view. The Tree_View is opened and shows multiple menu items.]

The white area below the menu bar represents a `TreeView`. I want the Tree_View menu to appear everywhere in the white area when right-clicking with the mouse.

This is the XAML code for the Tree_View object (mind the `foo` function there):

```
<MenuItem Name="Menu_Tree" Header="_Tree_View">
    <MenuItem Header="_New_Scene" IsCheckable="false" Click = foo/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Copy_This_Scene" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Remove_This_Scene" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="_New_Shot" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Copy_This_Shot" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Remove_This_Shot" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="_Move_This_Shot_Up" IsCheckable="false"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Move_This_Shot_Down" IsCheckable="false"/>
</MenuItem>
```

and this is the XAML code for the Tree_View object:

```
<Grid Name="TreeHolder" Column="0" Margin="20,10,10,10" Background="DimGray">
    <TreeView Name="myTree" MouseRightButtonDown="something" ToolTip="Right Click to Add or Remove Scenes and Scots.">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

This is the `something` function which should be triggered by right-click:

```
private void something(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    //cm.Items.Add("Add a New Scene ?", ... );
    Menu_Tree.ContextMenu = cm;
}
```

Since nothing works there, I want to ask the following:

a) How to make the Tree_view menu items appear in the Tree_View object white area as well?

b) If so, how will I make it an enabled menu, for example being able to trigger the `foo` function?

(In other worlds, make an exact copy of the menu list, make it visible with right click and make it work as well)

I strongly believe that it has to do with the `ContextMenu` which I am not able to use fairly, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, clarify, is it WPF?

Comment: Yes, it is WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items to add are `MenuItem`s. You can create each item as you would with any other object, set its `Header` property and assign a `Click` event handler. The `sender` is the `TreeView` itself.

```
private void something(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var cm = new ContextMenu();
   var newSceneMenuItem = new MenuItem { Header = "_New_Scene" };
   newSceneMenuItem.Click += OnNewSceneClick;
   cm.Items.Add(newSceneMenuItem);

   var treeView = (TreeView) sender;
   treeView.ContextMenu = cm;
}

private void OnNewSceneClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("I am a Message Box.", "New Scene clicked");
}
```

However, you can do this much easier in XAML without the right click handler.

```
<Grid Name="TreeHolder" Column="0" Margin="20,10,10,10" Background="DimGray">
   <TreeView Name="myTree" ToolTip="Right Click to Add or Remove Scenes and Scots.">
      <TreeView.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="_New_Scene" Click="foo"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy_This_Scene"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Remove_This_Scene"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_New_Shot"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy_This_Shot"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Remove_This_Shot"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Move_This_Shot_Up"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Move_This_Shot_Down"/>
         </ContextMenu>
      </TreeView.ContextMenu>
   </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

You do not need to set the `IsCheckable` to `false`, that is already the default value. Instead of assigning a `Click` event handler you could use [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), but I guess this would be a too advanced topic for you question, since it does not look like you are employing the MVVM pattern.